# How to correctly autocomplete script name in script tags using PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm has this amazing feature where when you press `Ctrl + Space + Space` between the `<script src=" "` tag it shows a dropdown of all the scripts and you can quickly insert the script's path.

My trouble is that it always adds a bunch of '../../../public/static' in front of the script (*even though I've marked the `public` directory as my resources root*).

Any way so that it starts from **`/static/`** instead of `../../../public/static` (get rid of the leading dots and slashes)

Answer (score 1):

Straight away -- not sure at all.

But here is some workaround: complete first folder in the path first (the `/static/` part) and then invoke that "list-all-scripts" completion.

This way the remaining path will be inserted using already completed `/static/` part.

I've just tested this in PhpStorm 2016.1.2 (inside .twig file though, but it should not matter).

Instead of `<script src="../../web/assets/vendor/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>` I'm getting `<script src="/assets/vendor/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>` which is what you need.

EDIT: I've checked your comment and it is indeed enough to just use leading `/` (instead of completing whole first folder) to have the rest path completed this way.

---

BTW -- it's not actually `Ctrl + Space + Space` -- it's <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> 2 times.

Comment: It works! I just need to add a slash it works great! thank you so much! By the way, I just want to add that you must have the `public` directory set as your *source root* too for it to work.

Comment: *" I just want to add that you must have the public directory set as your source root too for it to work."* The is absolute requirement -- otherwise IDE will be looking for this path relative to the project root.